# IPython notebook always shows "kernel starting, please wait..."

Tags: python-3.x, redhat, jupyter-notebook

platform: redhat x64, installed ipython notebook 3.0 through pyvenv-3.4

When I open a notebook, it always shows "kernel starting, please wait...".
But I can open IPython console.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: The reason turned out to be an obsolete firefox version. I updated firefox and it worked. Case closed.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you for posting this comment!  I also ran into this issue with firefox 37.0.1 and Jupyter 3.0.0

Comment: thanks for your question and this comment!

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem on multiple systems, and changing/updating browser solved it (as already written by OP).

Answer (score 3):

I meet this error message just now on ipython/jupyter notebook 4.0

And it turns out to by ad block plugin(for me is ublock)

This is probably due to this bug with the uBlock extension blocking WebSockets: [gorhill/uBlock#1604](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/1604)

Deactivating uBlock on notebook page resolved it for me, solusion maybe same to other ad block plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem right now on my Linux machine and up to date browser and even with a disabled uBlock. I was port-forwarding from a remote machine to my laptop while running Jupyter on the remote machine. Logging out of the ssh port-forwarding session (went to `htop` and killed the process) helped.

Comment: You are my savior!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was caused by ExpressVPN's whitelist (split-tunnel) feature interfering with Jupyter. I disabled split-tunnel and just used a browser VPN extension instead. FYI, NordVPN has a vaguely working split-tunnel feature whereas SurfShark, ExpressVPN and probably many others are complete fails.